# Use custom google maps markers using iconUrl SebmGoogleMap

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-cli

Since I have migrated from SystemJS to Webpack(Angular CLI) as the module bundler, my custom google maps makers are not no longer showing but the default ones does, the following is my template:

```
            <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map-marker>
                  <sebm-google-map-marker 
                     *ngFor="let nearMovingAgent of nearMovingAgents"
                    [latitude]="nearMovingAgent.obj.location[1]"
                    [longitude]="nearMovingAgent.obj.location[0]"                       
                    [iconUrl]= "nearMovingAgent.obj.agent_type == 'moving_company'? iconPathMC:iconPathSS" >

                    <sebm-google-map-info-window>                       
                        <h5 class="modal-title" *ngIf="nearMovingAgent.obj.agent_type == 'moving_company'"><small>Moving Company</small></h5>
                        <h5 class="modal-title" *ngIf="nearMovingAgent.obj.agent_type == 'self_standing'"><small>Self Standing Bakkie/Truck Owner</small></h5> 
                        <hr>
                        <p>{{nearMovingAgent.obj.address | capitalize }}</p>
                        <button class="btn view-details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" (click)="viewMovingAgentDetail(nearMovingAgent)">View Details</button>
                    </sebm-google-map-info-window>       
                  </sebm-google-map-marker>
        </sebm-google-map>
```

When i remove the attribute:

```
[iconUrl]= "nearMovingAgent.obj.agent_type == 'moving_company'? iconPathMC:iconPathSS"
```

The default icons are shown

And I have the following in my component class:

```
 iconPathMC: string = "../../../images/truck3.png";
 iconPathSS: string = "../../../images/pickup.png";
```

I have tried moving the above statements into ngOnInit() but I still cannot not see the icons on the map even though it throws no errors.
My server (NodeJS, Express and nodemon) shows a status of 200 for request. of the images:

```
GET /images/truck3.png
GET /images/pickup.png
GET /images/truck3.png 200 19.230 ms - 1347
GET /images/pickup.png 200 20.781 ms - 1347
```

Do I have to hook into a different component life-cycle to have the icons displayed, can anyone give me an idea of what i am missing.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have solved this by doing this in my component

```
declare var require: any;

markerIconUrl() {
   return require('../../../images/truck3.png')
}
```

Then called the method 'markerIconUrl' in my template like

```
<sebm-google-map-marker 
   *ngFor="let nearMovingAgent of nearMovingAgents"
    [iconUrl]="markerIconUrl()"                      
>
```

Albeit it solved the issue, I am still on research why it was an issue, it has to do with how Webpack works though.